# How to find out to which polygon each points belongs to in ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, arcmap, point-in-polygon

I have got a shapefile consisting of a number of polygons, and another shapefile with a number of points.

I want to add a column in the points shapefile. For each point, I want the column to contain the name of the polygon that surrounds it.

In simple terms, I just want to find out to which polygon each points belongs to. Any tips?

Here is the screenshot: [image]

Comment: Hi, look up http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00080000000q000000 for Spatial Join. Or use *Select by Location* from the selection menu: select one polygon, then use select by location to select all the points that are within that selected polygon, then select the next polygon... I can only see two polygons so the selection method might be the easiest.